# Setting up FTP on a server different from my site

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ftp

I'm attempting to set up FTP for our clients on a server different from that of our website.

We have a VM running Linux/Redhat that we use for some of our client's sites and I want to use that server as an FTP repository but I'm not certain on how to manage my DNS records to make this work properly.

Our DNS records are at www.mydomain.com. When I navigate to ftp.mydomain.com it gives me access to our website. But, I want have clients be able to go to ftp.mydomain.com and access their own ftp folder on the VM Linux server.

Do I need to..
1. Abandon this and create a zone on the linux machine for, say, clients.mydomain.com and create a new FTP CNAME in my DNS records that directs FTP traffic to clients.mydomain.com to the IP address of the Linux machine?

or 2. create some kind of 'A' record for ftp.mydomain.com?

I'm new to this level of administration and I'm not sure the best way to make it all work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNAMES redirect traffic from one subdomain to another.  For example, if you had an A record "www.mysite.com A 10.10.10.10" and you added "test.mysite.com CNAME www.mysite.com.", test.mysite.com would essentially be 10.10.10.10.

What you want is an A record ftp.mydomain.com pointing to your linux machine.  You would need to remove the existing record that's there already, and replace it with yours.  (There may not be one, it might be covered by a wildcard DNS entry).  Be warned, you won't be able to use ftp.mysite.com to access the web server anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you currently don't use anything for ftp..mydomain.com you can keep it the same.

What you *would* need to change is your firewall NAT rule. You'll want to create an NAT rule for anything that comes to ports 20 and 21 to be routed your the internal IP address of your VM Linux server.

Comment: I currently use ftp.mydomain.com to administer changes to our current website. I'm completely in the dark regarding the NAT rule you speak of, sorry. www.mydomain.com is a shared hosting environment but is the authoritative DNS. The linux server is through another hosting company. I don't know if that means anything to this topic or not.